# Windows 10 *NON DOMAIN* Can't create user account name longer than 20 chrs

Tags: windows-10

The subject line hopefully explains the problem. This happens on a new install as well. I am trying to add a non-MS account but can only enter 20 chrs. I need more. I'm sure I've done this before.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10,
The maximum length is 20 characters for a user account name. This limit applies to both local user accounts and Microsoft accounts. If you try to create a user account with a name that is longer than 20 characters, you will receive an error message.

If you want to create a user account with a name that is longer than 20 characters, you will need to create a free Microsoft account and use that to log in to your Windows 10 device. Microsoft accounts have a maximum length of 50 characters for the account name, so you should be able to use a longer name with a Microsoft account.

- To create a Microsoft account, Go to the Microsoft account [sign-up page](https://signup.live.com/).

Comment: Thank you but I am sure I did this about a year ago. Is this something new?

Comment: Nothing is new, If you already have an account just login & change name in the Microsoft account.